# Run script from 8:00 AM to 8 PM and if it does not end, kill it on 8:00 PM

Tags: postgresql, cron

I try to simulate the enterprise clients connecting the SQL server and selecting data from it. For now on, I managed to set up postgres on Windows 7 and wrote a script that selects some data from server from remote machine:

```
#!/bin/bash

data="$(psql -h 10.0.0.2 -d test -U postgres -c $'SELECT * FROM tablename;')"
#echo $data
```

Also, I measure its time with the `time` command.

What I need now, is to be able to run the script at 8:00 in the morning and stop it at 8:00 in the evening (that it should work the whole day). At night, the server does nothing (the script is not running), and the next day, I need to run it again and again, through the given number of days.

I played with cron a while ago, it seems a good solution, but the biggest concern is as follows: lets say, I run the script at 8:00 am but it will finish at 9:00 am - how can I know how long it will work to run it again to simulate the whole day traffic with no interruptions? Notice, that I don't know how long it takes to select the data - the content of the datais not important to me, I only have to select them and that's simply all.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: **how can I know how long it will work to run it again to simulate the whole day traffic with no interruptions**. Running the same *SELECT* statement over and over is unlikely to be a good representation of day-long traffic (unless all of your clients are literally doing exactly and only that). Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your cronjob up in a script like this, and call it something like psql_load_runner:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
  data="$(psql -h 10.0.0.2 -d test -U postgres -c $'SELECT * FROM tablename;')"
  #echo $data
done
```

Then set that to run a 08:00 each day - it will keep looping all day, which seems to match your requirement.

Then have another cron job that you run at 20:00 each day which just kills this one off, perhaps with a command like `killall -9 psql_load_runner`